# Can I save Xbox360 game progress on Xbox one?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm using the Xbox 360 disk version of Doom 3: BFG edition on my Xbox One.

After loading the game, I was prompted to select a storage device. The only option is cloud storage, which is 'offline' according to my system.

Will the game save normally like it does with all of my Xbox One games by using the cloud or is there an issue with my console?

Comment: Microsoft talk about this in their FAQ.. It seems like a tiny bit of research would have answered this question for you.

Comment: I did research but didn't find an answer. All i found was a way to turn it on from an Xbox 360 which didn't help

Comment: Of course, confirming that you do in fact have a Live Gold subscription?

Comment: Yes, I do. Until July 1st (not that I think a future date matters)

Comment: And you can access the other features of live / the support page does not list any service veing down? (it doesnt for me, but we might be in different regions)

Comment: Correct, I can use live & there are currently no services down in my area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Backwards compatibility will only save using the cloud. There is nothing wrong with your console.**

---

I was unable to locate the reference in the FAQ, so I simply contacted technical support through the chat function listed at the bottom.

> You must save to the cloud.      <sub>Ambassador    1:00 PM</sub>
>
> It is the only option available. <sub>Ambassador    1:01 PM</sub>

Comment: The ambassador reported that you should not need gold to access the cloud, and I personally know that although I am told I need gold for Xbox one, I do not. But I know you definitely do on 360, and the wording mae me uncertain, so I will test this out, myself.

Comment: also, if anybody would be able to confirm access to cloud over xbox one without gold, the earliest I believe I could have access to a silver account is atleast a month (I recall the free month of gold is automatic)

Comment: The use of the Cloud on the One is transparent and automatic. All saves are backed up to the Cloud and there is no possibility to have them remain exclusively on your console bar remaining offline all the time. They will also synchronize automatically. This is regardless of Live subscription.

Comment: @Eric, the specific context of the cloud for the question is Xbox 360. While you are playing on an Xbox One, you are using the Xbox 360 interface, through an emulator. As such, when the 360 game connects to the cloud, it is connecting "from an Xbox 360", where the cloud is not automated. This becomes more apparent when you have to select a memory location, as you still need to specify "cloud storage", despite being on a system where it is usually automatic.

Comment: Using backwards compatibility, the use of the cloud is also automatic and mandatory (if you wish to save at all) since you can only ever select the cloud as storage option. There is no "internal" storage you could select as the 360 is, essentially, virtualized.